# Shifting axis labels in Matlab subplot

Tags: matlab, offset, axis-labels, subplot

The figure below shows the problem I have with the overlaping y-axis labels.

**Before fix attempt**

[image: Result before fix attempt]

To fix this, I tried the following code (individually for each subplot; so h1 for subplot 1, h2 for subplot 2, and so on)

```
offset = 0.5
h1 = get(gca,'YLabel');
set(h1,'Position',get(h1,'Position') - [0 0 offset])
```

Whether I try an offset of 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, or higher; the result is always the following:

**After attempt**

[image: Result after fix attempt]

Am I using the command incorrectly or is there a frame around each subplot that prevents me from shifting the y-labels further to the left?

Answer (score 3):

You are applying an offset in the *Z direction* (the third element of the position vector, `[x y z]`). Instead, you want to apply the offset to the 1st element of the position vector to shift it in x.

```
offset = 0.5
h1 = get(gca,'YLabel');
set(h1,'Position',get(h1,'Position') - [offset 0 0])
```

Also the offset is in the same units as your x axis so you may want to adjust that appropriately. Alternately if you just want a certain percentage of padding you could use the `xlims` to compute the range of the x axis and use a percentage of that.

```
padPercent = 0.1;
offset = padPercent * diff(get(gca, 'xlim'));
```

And as an example

```
axes();
hlabel = ylabel('YLABEL');
offset = 0.075 * diff(get(gca, 'xlim'));
set(hlabel, 'Position', get(hlabel, 'Position') - [offset, 0 0])
```

[image]